# Swift: Are transactions really the most efficient way to store likes in Firebase?

Tags: swift, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, transactions

In the official [Firebase guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write), a transaction block is used to set likes for a post in the database.

In the example, the post's like count (aka starCount) is stored as an Int. The user ID of everyone who liked the post is stored as children under the post ID (under "stars").

```
-postID
  -starCount: 5281  // number of likes
  -stars            // list of everyone that liked the post
    -userID
    -userID
    -userID
    -userID
    ...
```

When a user likes a post, the following transaction is performed on that post's reference in the database:

```
ref.runTransactionBlock({ (currentData: MutableData) -> TransactionResult in

  // Store the post and current user
  if var post = currentData.value as? [String : AnyObject], let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {

    // Store the user ID of everyone that liked the post in a Dictionary
    var stars: Dictionary<String, Bool>
    stars = post["stars"] as? [String : Bool] ?? [:]

    // Store the number of likes 
    var starCount = post["starCount"] as? Int ?? 0

    // Unlike: If the user appears in the dictionary and has already liked the post,
    if let _ = stars[uid] 
    {
      // Unstar the post and remove self from stars
      starCount -= 1
      stars.removeValue(forKey: uid)
    } 
    // Like:
    else 
    {
      // Star the post and add self to stars
      starCount += 1
      stars[uid] = true
    }

    // Store the new like values for the post
    post["starCount"] = starCount as AnyObject?
    post["stars"] = stars as AnyObject?

    // Set value and report transaction success
    currentData.value = post

    return TransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
  }
  return TransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
})
```

**My question is: Isn't this an inefficient way of tracking the likes on a post?**

Suppose a post has 100,000+ likes. Every time the like button is clicked, the program must query all 100,000 user ID's in a dictionary, check if the current user ID exists in that dictionary, and update the database with the new dictionary of likes.

It can't be that bad if it's listed in the Firebase guide. But my gut feeling is that getting and setting such a large dictionary every single time a post is liked is not a good idea. There must be a better way of checking if the current user liked the post without querying every single user ID each time. This sounds just as expensive as calling childrenCount on a snapshot and getting the number of likes by counting.

In an app with millions of users and thousands of likes every second, the amount of data that's stored on the user end and sent back to the database seems overwhelming. Maybe I'm not fully understanding the nuances of the transaction function, but it seems like a dangerous thing to do as an app gains more users.

Thanks for reading, I'm curious to know what you think.

Comment: Can you point out, in the code in the question, what part corresponds to this statement *Every time the like button is clicked, the program must query all 100,000 user ID's in a dictionary,* as I am not seeing any queries at all in that code. I am seeing the code read a single child node `stars = post["stars"]` as an  Int, from a previously read in parent node `currentData`, and either incrementing it or decrementing it along with adding or removing the uid and then updating that node.

Comment: Maybe ‘query’ wasn’t the right term, but the user ID of everyone that liked the post must be stored in a dictionary in order for the code to work, whether it’s 10 people or 100,000 people. 

```stars = post["stars"]``` creates a dictonary of type ```[String: Bool]```, not an Int. 
```starCount``` is the variable that stores the like count as an Int.

Comment: Every use case will vary - the important part here is to ensure the count remains accurate through the transaction. If you have a large number of users uid's to store and there's a concern that it may overwhelm the device, just denormalize the data and/or store the uid's in another node. btw, Storing 100,000 uid's is 2Mb + the true bit that goes with each so a pretty small amount of data.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the 2Mb estimate. I was a bit confused because this is one of the few cases where a long list of data was being nested in a post instead of being given its own node in the database. If the like count is slightly off it's not a big deal, but I can see how this ensures accuracy for other use cases.